# Activate submit button using assigned key

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am having trouble with my codes, I'm planning to activate my php using javascript with my assigned key. Is it possible to activate the button with its unique ID by using assigned key using javascript? or any better ideas?

every submit button is linked to an id from my database, what i want is to activate the submit button linked with its id by using an assigned key rather than pressing the button

I have this existing code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_topic GROUP BY t_id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $t_id = $row['t_id'];
    $t_title = $row['t_title'];
    $t_desc = $row['t_desc'];
    $t_chap = $row['t_chap'];
    echo "<ul class='nav nav-sidebar'> ";
    echo "<li><a href=''><input type='submit'  name='$t_id' class='submitLink' value='$t_title'></a>";
    echo "</li></ul> ";

}


foreach($_POST as $key => $t_id){
    ${$key} = $t_id;

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_topic WHERE t_id = '$key'   ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $t_id = $row['t_id'];
        $t_titles = $row['t_title'];
        $t_descs = $row['t_desc'];
        $t_chaps = $row['t_chap'];
        $t_querys = $row['t_query'];


        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_topic ORDER BY t_chap  DESC LIMIT 1   ");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $t_chaps = $row['t_chap'];

            $nos = $t_chaps + 1;

            $up = mysql_query("UPDATE `tb_topic` SET `t_chap` = '$nos' WHERE t_id = '$t_id'  ");


        }
        echo "<script>window.location='i.php';</script>";

        if ($key == '4') {
            $up = mysql_query("UPDATE `tb_topic` SET `t_chap` = '0' ");
            echo "<script>window.location='i.php';</script>";


        }

    }


}
 <script>
document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 81) {
       //activate submit button id: 1
       location.reload();
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 87) {
       //activate submit button id: 2
       location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: Are you asking us to fill out the `//activate submit button id: n` code?

Comment: You should have your submit buttons in form tabs. Otherwise, just use buttons!

Comment: You should not have a key for each element. Instead you might specify a way to track the currently active form.

Comment: yes i want to fill the //activate comment i want to put a php function in that comment